# Validation rule to verify if at least two digits in a string

Tags: formula, validation-rule, regular-expressions

I would like to set up a validation rule to check that there is at least two digits in the string.
in Python I would go with this

```
NOT(REGEX(Field_Name__c, "(?=^(?:\D*\d\D*){2,}$)"))
```

But Salesforce seem to refuse this input for regex.

Does someone know how I would verify this.

Correct version: AAAA22AAAAA (at least 2 digits)
Wrong version: AAAAAAAAAA (no digits

Comment: Your expression would not work. You need the `{2,}` after `\d`.

Comment: Do you mean like this? `(?=^(?:\D*\d{2,}\D*)$)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `REGEX` function in Salesforce formulas needs to have `\` characters escaped ([documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm)).

I believe a straightforward formula like this should work:

```
NOT(REGEX(\\d{2,}))
```

This will check that there are at least two digits in sequence within the string. Your original regex may have some problems. I could not get it to match your expected input on [regexr.com](https://regexr.com/). I'm also making the assumption that the other characters do not matter, because your original pattern contains `\D*` which is 0 or more non-digit characters.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention it doesn't have to match characters consecutively, but a better exemple might be `AAAAA1AAA1` or `AAAAA2BBB3`

Answer (score 0):

I eventually went with `NOT(REGEX(Custom_Field__c, "^(?=(?:\\D*\\d){2})[a-zA-Z0-9]*$"))`

Thank you